# SRS Report Manager Inheritance

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This is regarding providing access in SSRS 2012.

My SSRS folder structure [In Browser] is looks like:

Public>Revenue_Reports>(Here are 5 reports)

Is there any way that I provide access to some user on 'Public' and 'Revenue_Reports' folder and he gets access to all 5 reports automatically?

I am asking this because it's a headache to add each user in security of each report. Sometimes there're 20 users that I've to add.

Note:- I am authorized to provide only 'Browser' access

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add permissions at the folder level in SSRS. Just go to the folder properties page in Report Manager, and adjust the permissions there.

To get to the folder properties, navigate to the folder in Report Manager, click on the Properties tab toward the top of the page. There is a Security link in the left nav.

Comment: Hi Richards, Thanks you for your reply. Even after giving access at folder level users are not able to see reports. Providing access on each report in necessary. Also I was unable to locate 'Properties tab' as mentioned by you. I  can only see 'New Folder', 'New data Source', 'Folder Setting', 'Upload File' on Left hand corner and 'Details View' on right hand corner

Comment: Sorry, the Security options are under Folder Settings in SSRS 2012. Providing access on each report is NOT necessary. You can do it at the folder level.